# how to train SVM using landmarks from CI2CV sdk to classify expressions?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, svm

I have an image such as this

[image]

after feeding the image to the CI2CV face-fit i get this

[image]

Along with a file containing info that i can't make sense of for the 66 landmarks detected in the following form, an explanation here would be great as to what the decimal values stand for

```
n_points: 66
{ 
54.9274 129.935
56.0976 142.037
58.2824 153.995
//there is 63 more lines
}
```

Is it possible to use just this information to classify the expression with SVM?

Comment: I presume that you're trying to use SVM (probably multi class) to classify expressions. So will SVM work? Probably, training an SVM depends on many things, and it's trial and error. You need to have sufficient amount of training data, and tune your SVM parameters to avoid over and underfitting. Get enough data for training, validation and testing, and play with it. Personally I think if the data is not ambiguous (less noise), then it's easier to train SVM. Not sure if other ML methods (e.g. ANN) are better for this case though.

Comment: i have a training set to classify 8 expressions, but the thing is how can i use the process of outputting the landmarks to classify an expression ? is there a better process ? the data set is quite big around 4 GB of images

Comment: Sadly I have never done classification of facial expression. But your landmarks are your feature vectors, try to train SVM with them, and do prediction with test data, try plot the precision recall curve. However, if I were you, I'd read some academic papers on it first. http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pmichel/publications/Michel-FacExpRecSVMAbstract.pdf is one of the papers that shows promising result.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I shall get to it right away

Comment: Don't forget to update here, I'm as curious as you are.